# Как сохранить значение в хранилище стейта Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Всем привет! Пишу телеграмм бота на питоне(aiogram). Мне нужно передать **переменную** из одного хэндлера в другой. Я пробовал сделать это через state.update_data(),но получал **список**, что-то типа {'Neutral': 0} на фото ниже
[image: Тут это {'Neutral': 0}]

Подскажите,каким образом можно передать именно **переменную**!

Вот код.

```
@dp.message_handler(state = Buttons.Neutral)
async def Fake(message: types.Message, state:FSMContext):
    if message.text ==("Начинаем!"):
        AllF = os.listdir(path="TimeDataBase") #Директория,из кот. берутся файлы 
        kvo = len(AllF)-1
        Rand = random.randint(0,kvo) #Выбор рандомного файла
        photo = open(f"TimeDataBase\meme{Rand}.jpg", "rb") # Отсылка этого файла
        await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo,reply_markup=ActionMenu) #Кнопка лайка/дизлайка
        await state.update_data(Neutral = Rand)
        await Buttons.Rate.set()

@dp.message_handler(state = Buttons.Rate)
async def Meme(message: types.Message, state:FSMContext):
    if message.text == ("❤️‍"):
        Rand = await state.get_data('Neutral')
        shutil.copyfile(f"TimeDataBase\meme{Rand}.jpg", f"SortedMemes\meme{Rand}.jpg")
```

Comment: Нужно больше инфы, кидайте код.

Comment: Покажите как вы получили такую ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно обновляете. Делайте так.

```
await state.update_data({"neutral": Rand})
```

Либо вообще вот так. (Только для 2-го айограма)

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
    data['neutral'] = Rand
```

UDP. Нет, я не совсем прав. Вы в целом засовываете правильно, но вот вытаскиваете - нет.

```
await state.get_data('Neutral')
```

Будет возвращать целой словарь, а аргумент `Neutral` будет значением по-умолчанию. Короче нужно было сделать так.

```
Rand = (await state.get_data())['Neutral']
```